OpenVPN works on Android mobile but doesn't work on Arch Linux
I have OpenVPN with username/password on my Android mobile which works perfectly. I installed OpenVPN on my Arch Linux and created a username/password file in home directory and wrote it terminal:
sudo openvpn --config my.ovpn --auth-user-pass pwd.txt

But upon connected, the server disconnected me. here is what I get at my Arch Linux:
2024-08-18 03:15:47 Note: --cipher is not set. OpenVPN versions before 2.5 defaulted to BF-CBC as fallback when cipher negotiation failed in this case. If you need this fallback please add '--data-ciphers-fallback BF-CBC' to your configuration and/or add BF-CBC to --data-ciphers.
2024-08-18 03:15:47 OpenVPN 2.6.12 [git:makepkg/038a94bae57a446c+] x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] [DCO] built on Jul 18 2024
2024-08-18 03:15:47 library versions: OpenSSL 3.3.1 4 Jun 2024, LZO 2.10
2024-08-18 03:15:47 DCO version: N/A
2024-08-18 03:15:52 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]95.81.90.11:1194
2024-08-18 03:15:52 Socket Buffers: R=[131072->131072] S=[16384->16384]
2024-08-18 03:15:52 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]95.81.90.11:1194
2024-08-18 03:15:52 TCP connection established with [AF_INET]95.81.90.11:1194
2024-08-18 03:15:52 TCPv4_CLIENT link local: (not bound)
2024-08-18 03:15:52 TCPv4_CLIENT link remote: [AF_INET]95.81.90.11:1194
2024-08-18 03:15:52 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]95.81.90.11:1194, sid=0fd91a29 d28b5547
2024-08-18 03:15:52 WARNING: this configuration may cache passwords in memory -- use the auth-nocache option to prevent this
2024-08-18 03:15:53 VERIFY OK: depth=1, C=US, ST=CA, L=SanFrancisco, O=MFT-HOST, OU=MFT-HOST, CN=MFT-HOST, name=MFT, emailAddress=admin@mft-host.com
2024-08-18 03:15:53 VERIFY KU OK
2024-08-18 03:15:53 Validating certificate extended key usage
2024-08-18 03:15:53 ++ Certificate has EKU (str) TLS Web Server Authentication, expects TLS Web Server Authentication
2024-08-18 03:15:53 VERIFY EKU OK
2024-08-18 03:15:53 VERIFY OK: depth=0, C=US, ST=CA, L=SanFrancisco, O=MFT-HOST, OU=MFT-HOST, CN=server, name=MFT, emailAddress=admin@mft-host.com
2024-08-18 03:15:53 Connection reset, restarting [0]
2024-08-18 03:15:53 SIGUSR1[soft,connection-reset] received, process restarting
2024-08-18 03:15:53 Restart pause, 1 second(s)
2024-08-18 03:15:54 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]62.60.174.243:1194
2024-08-18 03:15:54 Socket Buffers: R=[131072->131072] S=[16384->16384]
2024-08-18 03:15:54 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]62.60.174.243:1194
2024-08-18 03:15:54 TCP connection established with [AF_INET]62.60.174.243:1194
2024-08-18 03:15:54 TCPv4_CLIENT link local: (not bound)
2024-08-18 03:15:54 TCPv4_CLIENT link remote: [AF_INET]62.60.174.243:1194
2024-08-18 03:15:54 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]62.60.174.243:1194, sid=392b99d1 b7ad474f
2024-08-18 03:15:54 VERIFY OK: depth=1, C=US, ST=CA, L=SanFrancisco, O=MFT-HOST, OU=MFT-HOST, CN=MFT-HOST, name=MFT, emailAddress=admin@mft-host.com
2024-08-18 03:15:54 VERIFY KU OK
2024-08-18 03:15:54 Validating certificate extended key usage
2024-08-18 03:15:54 ++ Certificate has EKU (str) TLS Web Server Authentication, expects TLS Web Server Authentication
2024-08-18 03:15:54 VERIFY EKU OK
2024-08-18 03:15:54 VERIFY OK: depth=0, C=US, ST=CA, L=SanFrancisco, O=MFT-HOST, OU=MFT-HOST, CN=server, name=MFT, emailAddress=admin@mft-host.com
2024-08-18 03:15:54 Connection reset, restarting [0]
2024-08-18 03:15:54 SIGUSR1[soft,connection-reset] received, process restarting
2024-08-18 03:15:54 Restart pause, 1 second(s)
2024-08-18 03:15:55 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]95.81.90.92:1194
2024-08-18 03:15:55 Socket Buffers: R=[131072->131072] S=[16384->16384]
2024-08-18 03:15:55 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]95.81.90.92:1194
2024-08-18 03:15:55 TCP connection established with [AF_INET]95.81.90.92:1194
2024-08-18 03:15:55 TCPv4_CLIENT link local: (not bound)
2024-08-18 03:15:55 TCPv4_CLIENT link remote: [AF_INET]95.81.90.92:1194
2024-08-18 03:15:55 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]95.81.90.92:1194, sid=2e2bb418 dbb540e8
2024-08-18 03:15:56 VERIFY OK: depth=1, C=US, ST=CA, L=SanFrancisco, O=MFT-HOST, OU=MFT-HOST, CN=MFT-HOST, name=MFT, emailAddress=admin@mft-host.com
2024-08-18 03:15:56 VERIFY KU OK
2024-08-18 03:15:56 Validating certificate extended key usage
2024-08-18 03:15:56 ++ Certificate has EKU (str) TLS Web Server Authentication, expects TLS Web Server Authentication
2024-08-18 03:15:56 VERIFY EKU OK
2024-08-18 03:15:56 VERIFY OK: depth=0, C=US, ST=CA, L=SanFrancisco, O=MFT-HOST, OU=MFT-HOST, CN=server, name=MFT, emailAddress=admin@mft-host.com
2024-08-18 03:15:56 Connection reset, restarting [0]
2024-08-18 03:15:56 SIGUSR1[soft,connection-reset] received, process restarting
2024-08-18 03:15:56 Restart pause, 1 second(s)
2024-08-18 03:15:57 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]62.60.174.244:1194
2024-08-18 03:15:57 Socket Buffers: R=[131072->131072] S=[16384->16384]
2024-08-18 03:15:57 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]62.60.174.244:1194
2024-08-18 03:15:57 TCP connection established with [AF_INET]62.60.174.244:1194
2024-08-18 03:15:57 TCPv4_CLIENT link local: (not bound)
2024-08-18 03:15:57 TCPv4_CLIENT link remote: [AF_INET]62.60.174.244:1194
2024-08-18 03:15:57 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]62.60.174.244:1194, sid=7e492da0 a04da522
2024-08-18 03:15:57 VERIFY OK: depth=1, C=US, ST=CA, L=SanFrancisco, O=MFT-HOST, OU=MFT-HOST, CN=MFT-HOST, name=MFT, emailAddress=admin@mft-host.com
2024-08-18 03:15:57 VERIFY KU OK
2024-08-18 03:15:57 Validating certificate extended key usage
2024-08-18 03:15:57 ++ Certificate has EKU (str) TLS Web Server Authentication, expects TLS Web Server Authentication
2024-08-18 03:15:57 VERIFY EKU OK
2024-08-18 03:15:57 VERIFY OK: depth=0, C=US, ST=CA, L=SanFrancisco, O=MFT-HOST, OU=MFT-HOST, CN=server, name=MFT, emailAddress=admin@mft-host.com
2024-08-18 03:15:57 Connection reset, restarting [0]
2024-08-18 03:15:57 SIGUSR1[soft,connection-reset] received, process restarting
2024-08-18 03:15:57 Restart pause, 1 second(s)

and this is my config in my.ovpn:
dev tun
proto tcp-client
remote n2.mysite.in 1194
tls-client
persist-tun
persist-key
mute-replay-warnings
verb 3
auth-user-pass
redirect-gateway def1
--data-ciphers AES-256-CBC:AES-256-GCM:AES-128-GCM:CHACHA20-POLY1305
--disable-dco
auth SHA1
pull
remote-cert-tls server

I don't have access to server logs, but here is the Android log:
[Aug 18, 2004, 03:02:21]
PROTOCOL OPTIONS:
cipher: AES-256-CBC
digest: SHA1
key-derivation: OpenVPN PRF
compress: NONE
peer ID: -1

The ciphers match, so why am I disconnected?

I don't have any experience with OpenVPN configuration, but I googled the .ovpn content, and most returned data-ciphers, not --data-ciphers. Looks like the double dash is used for the command line argument, not the config file. Try removing the double dash in .ovpn?

@AndrewT.: I made change and still cannot connect.
